# What is the number of subgroups of order $7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ be a simple group of order $168$.

> What is the number of subgroups of order $7$?

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: no....Only I know Lagranges theorem.

Comment: Was this exercise really given just after introducing Lagrange?

Comment: Do you know cauchy theorem?? @user151456

Comment: I can't understand how this exercise is given assuming *only* Lagrange's Theorem and without knowing Sylow theorems. Either there's some very sneaky way to overcome that or else this is a gross mistake.

Answer (score 2):

you must have to be familiar with sylow theorem, 
 168=2*2*2*3*7= 2^3 * 3 * 7. hence according to sylow theorem their must be sylow subgroup of order7. now let denote number of sylow 7 subgroup by #7 then #7≡1mod7. then only possibilities of #7 are 1,8,15,22,29....we cannot take #7 greater than 22 because 29*7= 203 which exceed order of group. then only possibility of #7 are 1,8,15,22. now #7 must divides 168= 2*2*2*3*7 hence only possibilities remain for #7 are 1,8. now if there is only one #7 then that must be normal subroup according to one of sylow result and this is contradiction to definition of simple group, becuse simple group contain no proper nontrivial normal subgroup. hence there must be more one #7 this implies #7 = 8.  hence there are 8 subgroups of order 7 in simple group of order 168.